# SCSS Grid bug using Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, css-grid

I recently wrote a simple TicTacToe web app using Angular and deployed it [here](https://tictactoe-angular.vercel.app/).

Whenever I inspect in browser on my laptop, [all mobile dimensions look fine](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/55413326/178561555-b8518e4f-8a53-4b52-b003-0e3c5c2f690e.png).

But when I visit the website on mobile devices, the styling messes up.
[iPhone 7+ doesn't display the grid](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/55413326/178561939-81865d89-b857-447d-9f6c-71697afc0f5f.png).

iPhone SE displays a [wacky grid](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/55413326/178563642-3f73b201-32ce-4ba7-b716-65282aac2dfd.png).

I've tried different browsers on desktop and mobile and the results are the same as above.

SCSS for the 3x3 game board:

```
main {

    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-gap: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 12px;
    align-items: center;
    

}

app-square {

    border-radius: 12px;
    height: 100px;
}



.newGameButton:hover {

    color: bisque;
    background-color: black;
}
```

SCSS for the squares in the game board:

.square is a button.

```
.square { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    font-size: 5em !important; 
    opacity: 0.9; 
    border: none; 
    border-radius: 12px;

}

.square:hover {

    opacity: 1;
   
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.Xsquare { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    font-size: 5em !important; 
    opacity: 0.9; 
    border: none; 
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #14F195;

}

.Osquare { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    font-size: 5em !important; 
    opacity: 0.9; 
    border: none; 
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #9945FF;

}
```

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/AlexRubik/tictactoe-angular)

UPDATE 1: Changed the square button into a div and it fixed it but this still doesn't explain why the button styling bugs.

Comment: Have you updated your iOS version? Because [grid is not supported by old Safari](https://caniuse.com/?search=grid)

Comment: @Eugene I've tried different mobile browsers on iPhones with latest iOS.